# New Item script does not apply after postback

Tags: javascript, infopath, newform, multiline-text-field

I have a simple javascript code on a new item page, it limits the number of characters for a multi-line field. After I select someone in the people picker, the form does a quick postback and load, and my character limit no longer applies. Is there a way to reload my script once the people picker does its postback?

I am in Office 365, here is the character limit script, I should also mention this is a custom Infopath form:

```
function exploder(){
    $("#ctl00_ctl40_g_eefaaee7_0d73_4a99_9ea5_9baa41a0e15c_FormControl0_V1_I1_T22").attr("maxlength", "255");
}
function explodes(){
    $("#ctl00_ctl40_g_eefaaee7_0d73_4a99_9ea5_9baa41a0e15c_FormControl0_V1_I1_T23").attr("maxlength", "255");
}
setTimeout(exploder, 3000);
setTimeout(explodes, 3000);
```

Comment: What version are you using? in my SPOnline I tried creating a list with people picker and incorporated a script for the character limit and it works fine. no post back for people picker. Can you show me your js.

Comment: Kindly add Code snippet you wrote to apply Character Limit

Comment: Did you found any solution ? I am having the same issue.

Comment: I did find a solution, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, it basically loops your javascript every two seconds. Just insert your code where it's noted and you can change the 2000 to any interval you want (1000 = 1 second)

```
<script>

  window.setInterval(function(){

    //code goes here

  }, 2000);

</script>
```